# How to run cucumber feature file from java code not from JUnit Runner

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java, qaf

I want to run cucumber feature file from java code.

currently we are running form JUnit Runner

```
package com.compareglobalgroup.testscript;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

    @CucumberOptions(features = { "src/test/resources/feature/BB" }, glue = { "com.compareglobalgroup.stepdefs.BB",
        "com.compareglobalgroup.cucumber.hooks" }, plugin = {
                "json:cucumberreport/json/cucumberreport.json" }, tags = { ""
                        + "@Test" })
    public class TestRunnerBB extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

I don't want to use this instead I want to run this  using java program because I want to pass tags at run time from command line or jenkins.

Answer (score 10):

Call the static main method of [Main](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/cli/Main.java) class in the package `cucumber.api.cli` that corresponds to running cucumber from the command line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

    Main.main(new String[]{"-g", "classpath to step definition file", "Full path to feature file"});

          // My stepdefinition is inside java package at cucumber.sample.test
          // My feature file is inside src/test/resources/features/featurefile.feature

        }
```

For additional parameters like tags or plugin use `"-t","@Tags"`. **Important the feature file path has to be the last option.**

BTW - In the your example you are running with a TestNG cucumber runner.

Comment: how can I referece the external step definition file (jar lib)?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [qaf-gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) where you don't need to use junit or other runner. All you need to specify step provider package and feature file(s) or dir to run. For example:

```
<test name="Gherkin-QAF-Test">
   <parameter name="step.provider.pkg" value="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.impl.step.qaf" />
   <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="resources/features" />
   <classes>
      <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
   </classes>
</test>
```

You can walk through [qaf-step-by-step-tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki)

Comment: Thanks bro Very useful. I will use this in future as I have already create my framework.