# Can I run cucumber tests through endpoints as an API?

Tags: java, cucumber, e2e-testing, cucumber-jvm

I created a project using cucumber to perform e2e tests of various apis I consume. I would like to know if I can run these tests through endpoints to further automate the application that was created.

That way I would be able to upload this app and would not need to keep calling locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that if you create a Rest API with a get method which executes the test runner when called.

[How to run cucumber feature file from java code not from JUnit Runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807307/how-to-run-cucumber-feature-file-from-java-code-not-from-junit-runner)

But I don't recommend you to do that since what you are trying to achieve seems to me similar to a pipeline definition.

If you're in touch with the developers of these APIs, you can speak with them about including your test cases in their pipeline, since they probably have one in place.

If, for some reason, you still want to trigger your tests remotely and set it up by your own, I would recommend you to start reading about Jenkins. You can host it on any machine and run your tests from there, accessing from any machine to your jenkins instance:

https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/cucumber-jenkins-tutorial/

If your code is hosted in any platform like github or gitlab, they already have its own way of creating pipelines and you can use it to run your tests. Read about Gitlab pipelines or Github actions.